# How to get text/data from another website or time

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, time

I'm doing a school project, a christmas calendar, where every day untill christmas a new slot opens ect. But I'm having trouble to find a good way to get the current date/time to make sure that people can't open a slot before that slots set date. So either I have to get the time of the server the I'm hosting the website on or either I have to get the current time/date from another website somehow.
Or if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Do you use PHP at your server?

Comment: If you determine if the door can be opened in client side JS, then the door can be opened at any time. The check for the time on the server can be bypassed. You need to rethink your approach and have your server refuse to send the data that describes what is behind the door before the given data.

Comment: Use date from JS and validate that date server-side.

Comment: Any code available?I would suggest geting date with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a little script on the serverside of your page. Just let the client sent his time to the server and the server checks if it is allowed to open the element or not.

On the other way i think you should have something like an AJAX request to get the "gift" behind a door, because you shouldn´t have it in the pagecode. Why dont you check on the AJAX request on the server if the time has come or not?

---

EDIT:
Additional ideas:
Behind door 15 you can have an AJAX request like `getDataForDay.php?day=15` and on your script you can check if it is day 15 and return the html for the gift and if not send an error state like "Wrong Day"

---

EDIT2:

On the other way another view of your "problem". I dont know what you want to hide behind the doors, bat maybe it isnt something important (like prizes e.g.) and only funny things like pictures or texts.
On that case i would just use js an make everything on client side. If the user wants to "cheat" an manipulate the doors he takes his fun and the idear behind such an calendar.

(Your chocolate calendar at home hasn´t a timelock either) ;-)

Comment: Our teacher is forcing us to stay after school to make a calendar for his on-side company. But there are some real prizes. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Glad i was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest getting the date by the server. You can't get data from another server with Javascript ([Same Origin Policy means that JS can only send AJAX requests to the same domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). If you want to get the time from the server, in PHP you do that using [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). For most use cases however, you can just use the clients time, by getting the date [client side](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) and then validating this date on the PHP side

Answer (score 0):

You should do the whole date-based refusal policy on server side of your application. Users can always mess with your client-side JavaScript or with the communication between the client and the server.